# Merge pairs in a list that have the same 1st element by averaging the the 2nd elements

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I'm trying to do interpolation on a large list of data of the format `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, ..., {xn, yn}}` that is exported from a simulation.

Unfortunately, the exported data has some points `{x_(i), y_(i)}` and `{x_(i + 1), y_(i + 1)}` that share the same x point: `x_(i) = x_(i + 1)`. This is just because of poor precision in the export process from the simulation.

The interpolation function doesn't like the fact that there are duplicate points that share the same x value, and gives me an error message with no output interpolation.

I want to take the duplicate points `{x_(i), y_(i)}` and `{x_(i + 1), y_(i + 1)}`, average `y_(i)` and `y_(i + 1)` and remove `x_(i + 1)` from the list. The final list should have no duplicates.

It should be pretty straightforward. I'm just a little slow at programming, because I don't have to do it very often.

Comment: Thanks guys! Both of these seem to work, and are more elegant than what I could have come up with.

Answer (score 4):

When the x-values are *exact* duplicates, the following might work (`data` is the n x 2 -matrix with the data points).

```
KeySort@GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Mean]
```

This produces an association. You may obtain a list again with

```
Transpose[ 
 Through[{Keys, Values}[
  KeySort@GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Mean]]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Or go straight to the list with `data2 = {#[[1, 1]], Mean[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@
  GatherBy[data, First]`

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {1, 6}};

assocs = AssociationThread @* Apply[Rule] /@ data
```

> <|1 -> 2|>, <|3 -> 4|>, <|5 -> 6|>, <|1 -> 6|>}

```
means = Merge[Mean][assocs]
```

> <|1 -> 4, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6|>

```
List @@@ Normal @ means
```

> {{1, 4}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {1, 2}};

data2 = Union[data, SameTest -> (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &)]

(* {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} *)
```

If the x values are not exact duplicates then you can use:

```
SameTest -> (Abs[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] < minDifference &)
```

with minDifference set to an appropriate value.

Comment: My answer does not in fact average the y values. I voted for Henrick’s answer!